# Floated thumbnail gallery, different sizes, how to handle?

Tags: css, image, gallery, css-float, thumbnails

When simply doing float:left to all thumbnails of the same size, a gallery looks great. But when different size thumbnails come in to play, that is no longer the case.

What is the best way to handle different size thumbnails? Do I need to use tables instead?

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to give each thumbnail a div container with a fixed size, so that every thumbnail takes the same space. I mean, don't resize your thumbnails.
The picture in the div should be centered.

Answer (score 13):

None of the possible CSS solutions look particularly good.

I recommend using JavaScript+jQuery instead, specifically one of these plugins:

- http://masonry.desandro.com/
- http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: those plugins are truly amazing

Answer (score 2):

I have used following plugin, it's working fine :

http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

For those in 2017 looking for a gallery for different sized images, check this css-tricks article: https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/